# Does Proof of Authority make blockchain network centralized?

Tags: blockchain

I'm doing a research about blockchain's Proof of Authority concept. And as far as I'm concerned, this method make blockchain network more "untrustworthy", as we now need to trust some person with a high reputation - just like working with traditional banks. Should it be opposite to the core value of blockchain where no trust is needed?

Comment: yes, it makes it centralized by the "authorities", which is opposite of the purpose of blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes PoA consensus is not truly distributed and is used only when the trust is distributed(in some sense though!) but at the cost of the real decentralization that blockchains are purposed to achieve.But you know PoS(Proof of stake) has some limitations that one needs to address.I would like to give an example explaining the problem with PoS.Here in this example you can see the same size stake may be valued differently by different actors in the PoS consensus.

Suppose lets say you and me, you the early adopter of the blockchain technology with a massive portfolio of digital assets, and me, a newbie who is just exploring the emerging token economy. Let’s say we both hold the same stake in a hypothetical network, SafeNetwork, 1,000 SNC each. In isolation, everyone could assume that we both are equally interested in SafeNetwork success but cannot be as confident in this proposition, however, when we take our other holdings into consideration. If 1,000 SNF is only 1% of your total wealth, while for me it represents nearly 50%, our incentives are tough to compare. You might care about SafeNetwork much less than i do, even though we have the same stake. Consequently, your desire to act in the interest of the network might also not be as strong as mine.

This is a scenario where PoS alone is not giving us a full transparency.We can easily see that we fail to preserve the staking concept, with scarcity and measurability of stake, while ensuring that all who place that stake value it similarly, regardless of other circumstances.

This is PoA fits in.Its just the other way of PoS where instead of stake with the monetary value, a validator’s identity performs the role of stake.Identity as a form of stake is also scarce but unlike PoS,where anyone can have multiple stakes but here we have only and only one identity per person.Unless and until any criminal or psychological impacts are taken into considerations!!!!.

Putting it together,when you stake your identity you are voluntarily disclosing who you are in exchange for the right to validate the blocks. This means that the benefits you derive from it are public and so are the nefarious actions you might undertake.So PoA is, by definition, centralised. If the authority nodes go rogue, or fail to reach consensus, the network is useless.Adapting PoA would have to come from some benefit of its centralization, and a very high level of trust in the trusted authorities.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)